# ios: In memory data store

Tags: ios, core-data, in-memory-database

I want to create an in memory data store with core data on the iphone in the following way:

- The data of the store is saved to disk in an encrypted file (max size 400kb)
- The encrypted file is loaded completly into memory and afterwards I will decrypt it so that I have some data array in memory
- I want to tell the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to use this data array which is the store I want to use.
- At certain points in the code the current in memory data store will be copied to another data array, encrypted and stored to disk such that the data on disk corresponds always to the most recent version of the data.

I must do that because the data is sensitive user data that absolutly cannot be stored in a plain database.

In my app I already implemented a version where each property of the managed objects are encrypted, such that the sqlite database which is stored on disk contains only cryptic unreadable values. Unfortunatly it turned out to be too slow to encrypt an decrypt everything everytime on the fly.

First off: Is this possible?
Secondly: Might there be some things I need to pay attention to?

Comment: Another alternative would be to port SQLCipher to iOS.

Comment: Interessting. But I suppose that does not work in conjunction with core data?

Comment: I don't know.  It's a plug-replacement for SQLite, but I don't know if you can somehow get Core Data to plug in -- Have never used Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be of any help to you but in iOS5 persistent stores now store data in an encrypted format on disk. This is also an option in iOS4. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW54).

> For applications built for iOS 5.0 or later, persistent stores now store data by default in an encrypted format on disk. The default protection level prevents access to the data until after the user unlocks the device for the first time. You can change the protection level by assigning a custom value to the NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey key when configuring your persistent stores. For additional information about the data protection that are new in iOS 5.0, see “Data Protection Improvements.”

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as far as I understand this, the data would only be protected by the 4 digit code the user uses to unlock the phone. I think this solution is insufficient for my task.

Comment: Ok - not knowing your precise requirements I just thought I'd throw it out there.